# Can connect to internet but not to router

Tags: router, streaming

A few computers are connected to a local TP-LINK router. The Internet connection speed is 6Mbps.

Until last week there were no network issues but now, one of them, responsible for streaming, is dropping frames.

I tried to access the router page to see if there are issues reported by the router, but I no longer can access 192.168.0.1.

If I reboot the router, for a few minutes, the device is accessible.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a bug in TD-896x, 895x and other versions of TP-Link wifi routers.

I have a TP-Link TD-8961ND V3 and it has the same problem. Every time you restart the device you can access the Admin Web portal, but after 24 hours (sometimes more) you loose the access. The WEB, Telnet and SNMP access to the device are rejected.

Updating firmware did not solve the problem. Currently with Firmware Version Build 140305 Rel.04531

The only solution is to reset or power cycle the device.

There are many reports of this problem in TP-Link forums but it has not been adressed by the manufacturer.

As you said, internet access through the router is not affected, only the management functions.

Answer (score 0):

Run winipcfg and check that your computers are actually using that IP as the gateway.

I think that IP is available for the first few minutes because the router have not fully configured itself in that time.

Answer (score 0):

upgrade firmware is the only solution

I had a similar issue with TD-W8961NDv3 router but after a firmware upgrade it seems to be working fine.

Firmware can be found [**here**](http://www.tp-link.com/en/download-center.html).

Comment: Are you able to provide a link to the firmware release notes that solved your problem?